# How can I connect to a MySQL database with custom value?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJs project. There is a connection to different databases that have already been created in advance.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "***,
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "***",
      "password": "***",
      "database": "db_name",
      "autoLoadEntities": true,
      "name": "users_db",
      "synchronize": true
    }),
```

When user registers, a database is created with his [user_id]. And I need to add data in this db. How can I connect to his database by taking his id? I can't pass data to app.module or is there some other way? I have never worked with typeorm before.

Answer (score 0):

TypeOrm has some docs on this [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/multiple-connections#using-multiple-databases-in-a-single-connection).

An example from those docs:

```
const users = await connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .select()
    .from("secondDB.user", "user")
    .addFrom("thirdDB.photo", "photo")
    .andWhere("photo.userId = user.id")
    .getMany();
```

> This feature is supported only in mysql and mssql databases.

Where `secondDB` and `thirdDB` are both different databases within the same connection.

You'll use this almost exactly the same as you normally would in Nest.  Set up with `.forRoot()` in the app module, inject the repository or connection, and then create the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change if you have one instance your app.
If you create for each user separate instance your app it is possible.
But why you want change this ?

Use env like here `username: process.env.POSTGRES_DB_USERNAME,`

But if you want in any entity add whoCreated, whoUpdated you need add just info about logged user to you service update/save.